# Atrrib CMD Access Denied

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, security, command-line-interface, access-control-list

I'm trying to remove the special attribute from the folder **C:\windows\tasks** using the command **attrib -s C:\windows\tasks** however I'm getting:

> Access denied - C:\windows\Tasks

I am a local administrator on the server (It's Windows 2003 SP2) and I didn't find any special GPO applied to those settings.

What other reasons could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a solution [like this, with cacls](http://www.avianwaves.com/Blog/default.aspx?id=83&t=Easy-Way-to-Change-Permissions-on-the-Wi), or use the more-powerful [subinacl tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en) which may well let you do it in-place.

Answer (score 0):

try taking ownership of the file/directory. you might use [takeown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755342(WS.10).aspx) from [w2003 resource toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).

Comment: Used takeown /f C:\windows\tasks

Got > SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\windows\tasks" now owned by user "Domain\User".

Still getting access denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try booting up in safe mode or command prompt mode and trying it.

Comment: I can't try this, it's a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

pQd is correct, Ownership is likely the issue here.

I'd try using the Win2K3 native Ownership tools before a third party tool.  Right click on the folder, and select Properties, select the Security Tab, then Click on the Advanced Button, and select the Ownership tab.  From here you can reassign ownership to yourself,  applying the changes to child objects if necessary.
Then you should be able to make the changes you are looking for.

Comment: right... although i wouldnt call windows 2003 resource toolkit from almighty microsoft a 3rd party tool ;-]

Comment: You can't access the security tab. This specific folder has the +s attribute. This attribute removes all the administrative tabs, except for "General

Comment: pQD, Sorry, I did not fully read your answer,  I once had a tech bring in a utility called takeown, but it was from someone else, so I missed that you were pointing to the W2k3 Resource Kit.  My Bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to remove the system attribute from the system folder?  You'll notice that it has a shell special icon indicting it is the tasks location.  Take ownership if th asks folder and you should be able to change it.

Comment: I need to remove it so I can give a special group permissions to it. This KB has more detail > http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926959